I got an error during Azure Classic Migration to ARM, it did validate then when Prepare if error
How to fix it, I don't have a VM a simple Web Role, Worker Role size small
I looked through their suggested documentation, nothing close to the error.
I checked the size of my service both are small, I do not have a VM to upgrade, the only thing I could do is change the Windows version currently version 12 R2 to 16, .. 22


I have added this image in my original question, I couldn't see it when post it

You still need to edit the original question to include it. If you cannot see it after posting, review if you are using the right Markdown image syntax ![text](link).
